# Creating a php redirect to a html slide

Tags: php, html

Hi I am trying to create a php statement the redirects you back to a set slide on my html slideshow on another page. However, although the data inserts into my database, it will not redirect back to the slide on my html page.

I have already tried this using html anchor pints, but they arent working.

my php file...

```
<?php

$url = 'Details.html';
$anchor = 'slide3';

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo 'Request Submitted';
    echo<<<JS
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.location.href="$url?$query_string#$anchor";
</script>
JS; 
} else {
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
```

and the slide I am trying to link it to...

```
<div class="mySlides w3-container w3-blue" id="slide3">
<h1 class="w3-wide w3-center"><b>BUSINESS DETAILS</b></h1>
<div class="w3-center w3-container w3-content w3-padding-16">
<form action="Addition.php" method="post">
      Business Name : <input type="text" name="bname">
              <br>
              <br>
      Business Type : <input type="text" name="btype">
              <br>
              <br>
              <button class="w3-button w3-green" 
  onclick="plusDivs(1)">Submit and Continue</button>
 </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't mix PHP and JS unless you have a good reason to. Use `header('Location: name_of_file.html'); exit;` to redirect.

Comment: `if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){` WHERE IS `$sql` and `$con` defined. OR Why are you running a query you dont seem to actually use

Comment: Also WHERE does `$query_string` come from??

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Don't mix PHP and JS unless you have a good reason to. Use `header('Location: name_of_file.html');` and finally `exit;` or `die();` to redirect.

```
<?php

$url = 'Details.html#slide3';

if (...){
    header('Location: ' . $url); 
    exit;
}
```